# Javascript date weirdness between Firefox and everyone else

Tags: javascript, firefox

Does anyone know why in Firefox if you execute the code below it will validate it as a date if the string passed in is four numbers and only four numbers? In every other browser I tested with (IE, Chrome) it will always return as not a date.

Being that the spec, as pointed out by Marcel Korpel below, states that it should fall back to use the Firefox's implementation-specific fall back I am really wondering why Firefox's fall back displays this anomaly.

```
function isDate(sDate) {  
    var temp = new Date(sDate);  
    if (temp.toString() == "NaN" || temp.toString() == "Invalid Date") {  
        alert("Not a Date");  
    } else {  
        alert("Is a Date!");  
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code with 4 spaces, don't use backticks the way you did.

Comment: return true in one branch, and don't return anything in another... ???!?

Comment: Yea I was trying to make a quick and dirty isDate function and forgot to add in the return false. Let me just remove the return true for this discussion.

Comment: Why do you use `toString` to test for `NaN`? Why not use `isNaN(temp)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass a string to the `Date` constructor, the string should be in a format recognized by the [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method ([IETF-compliant RFC 1123 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123)) (source: [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)). Everything else results in implementation specific behaviour and will vary across browsers.

I suggest you don't use strings at all and either use three numbers representing year, month and day (mind that month numbers begin at 0 (= January)), *or* use one number, the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

**UPDATE:** seeing your example,

```
var a = new Date('0123');
console.log(a);
```

outputs

```
Fri Jan 01 0123 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

so Firefox apparently recognizes `'0123'` as a year number.

**UPDATE 2:** I think [MDC's description of `Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Description) contains the answer to your question:

> Starting in JavaScript 1.8.5, a subset of [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) formatted date strings can also be parsed.

The ISO 8601 page specifies (section 'Formats'):

> Year:
>         YYYY (eg 1997)
> Year and month:
>         YYYY-MM (eg 1997-07)
> Complete date:
>         YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16)

So when relying on ISO 8601, a string only containing four numbers will be recognized as a year number.

Comment: I understand it is not compliant, I was just wondering why Firefox would display this behavior.

Comment: @Brian: it's just because of that, it's behaviour is not specified; according to the [ECMAScript spec](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.9.4.2), “[i]f the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.” The `Date` constructor *should* return `NaN` if the string isn't recognized as a date. It's just that some browsers are more forgiving than others.

Comment: I guess I am really asking why Firefox's implementation-specific fall back will return NaN for '123' but a date for '0123'. Should I edit my post to better qualify my question?

Comment: That is even odder still. So for some reason Firefox will accept '0000' as a valid year? Might this be a bug?

Comment: Ahh now I get it. When passing in a string, Firefox attempts to do a date.parse on it and '1234' happens to work where as '123' does not.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do not rely on date validation in javascript. The local date time format may create some problem with the javascript date object.

use following approach

- show non editable text box
- on focus of the textbox show calendar
- do empty validation, it the field has to be mandatory
- no need to perform date validations as if the value of text box is not empty, it will be definitely date. We are not allowing user to enter anything else and the selected value from the calendar is always gonna be Date :)

Answer (score 1):

This works in all browsers -

> new Date('2001/01/31 12:00:00 AM')

Comment: You just gave me the answer why my object failed when I applied on it new Date() object creation. Firefox just fails when I pass Dash '-' to it. Chrome doesn`t. Replacing to '/' did the job

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue as with this in firefox, for some reasons I cannot explain
any 4 digit numeric chars is a valid date in FF, in other browsers this is NaN:

A bit nasty work-around for FF but, this worked for me:

```
function isDate(sDate) {  
    if(sDate.match(/^\d{4}$/))
       return false;
    var temp = new Date(sDate);  
    if (temp.toString() == "NaN" || temp.toString() == "Invalid Date") {  
        alert("Not a Date");  
    } else {  
        alert("Is a Date!");  
        return true;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! I think I will use something like this in my code as well.